# Improve performance Largest Contentful Paint element

Tags: html

When I start my website it returns several images like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.dep1').hide();
  $('.dep2').hide();
  $('.dep3').hide();
  $('.dep4').hide();
  $('.dep5').hide();
  $('.dep6').hide();
  $('.dep7').hide();
  $.getJSON('dadosinf.php', function (data) {
    $.getJSON('session.php', function (data1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        Colaborador = data1[i][0];
        Grupo = data1[i][2];
      }
      var linha = ``;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          linha += `<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">                   
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item btn btn-warning histor-uten">
                          <div class="profile-photo-div" id="profile-photo-div">
                            <div class="profile-img-div" id="profile-img-div" style="height: 250px;">
                                <div id="loader"></div>                            
                                <img id="profile-img" src="/assets/utente/${data[i][3]}" loading="lazy">                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="profile-buttons-div">
                              <div class="profile-img-input" id="profile-img-input">                    
                                  <p class="butttton" id="change-photo-label" style="white-space: initial; word-wrap: break-word !important;">#${data[i][1]} ${data[i][2]}</p>
                                  <p class="butttton" id="change-photo-label"><i class='fa fa-house' aria-hidden='true'></i> ${data[i][4]} <i class='fa fa-bed' aria-hidden='true'></i> ${data[i][5]} Nº Roupa: ${data[i][6]}</p>  
                                  <input type="hidden" name="id_utt" value="${data[i][1]}">                
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </a>
                      </div>`;
       }
      $(".tesssste").html(linha);
      $('.dep').show();
      $('#minhadiv105').show();
    });
  });
});
```

but when I analyze it in Lighthouse on Google Chrome it returns this message:

> Largest Contentful Paint element 3,850 ms
> This is the largest contentful element painted within the viewport.

| Phase | % of LCP | Timing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TTFB | 5% | 190 ms |
| Load Delay | 92% | 3,540 ms |
| Load Time | 1% | 50 ms |
| Render Delay | 2% | 70 ms |

How can I improve the performance of this code?

Comment: Hi, did you optimize your images? try to compress and resize images to reduce their file size without compromising quality. Also consider using modern image formats like WebP.

Comment: One easy improvement here is to avoid making two API calls in series, the call to `session.php` doesn't start until the call to `dadosinf.php` is complete. Make those calls in parallel and you will just have to wait for the longer of the two calls, rather than both combined.

Comment: For the above code, if the LCP image will be the same for each page load, you may try to `preload` (resource hints) the image.. Or if `session.php` and `dadosinf.php` is requested everytime on page load, you may consider preloading them as well..

Comment: @James Ashok The images are all different but the session.php and datainf.php are always prompted, how do I preload them